# SQLITE_ERROR during Query Prepare Phase in C++

Tags: c++, sqlite

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include <stdio.h>

const char dbName[] = {"/trial.sqlite"};

std::string quoteSql( std::string &s );

int main(){


std::string szSQL;
std::string tableName;

tableName = "Nodes";
int result;

const char *pzTest;

sqlite3_stmt *statement;

sqlite3 *db;

std::string nodename;

int count;

nodename = "KMLB1";

szSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Nodes WHERE NODENAME = ?";

result = sqlite3_open(dbName,&db);
if(result){
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
}

result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,szSQL.c_str(),strlen(szSQL.c_str()),&statement,&pzTest);
if(result){
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
}

sqlite3_bind_text(statement,1,nodename.c_str(),-1,0);

result = sqlite3_step(statement);
if(result){
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
}
count = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
if(count == 0){
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
}

sqlite3_finalize(statement);
sqlite3_close(db);


return 0;
}

std::string quoteSql( std::string &s ) {
return std::string("'") + s + std::string("'");
}
```

I coded an experimental and basic C++ SQLite console application above. There is no problem on the compilation phase but I get SQLITE_ERROR status code on the sqlite_prepare_v2() function's line. I couldn't even get the cause of problem.

In addition I would like to know that if I could get the row count which's NODENAME is KMLB1 by this code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`sqlite3_errmsg`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) to find out what went wrong.

Please note that the return values `SQLITE_ROW` and `SQLITE_DONE` of [`sqlite3_step`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) are not zero, and that [`sqlite3_column_int`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) does not return an error code.